# Java: Removing swear words

Tags: java, string

mind if I ask a question? How do you make a code that censor a swear words? For example
Enter a string: Holy Crap!
Output: Holy ****!
How do you this type of program in java?

Comment: Have you looked at `java.lang.String#replace()` as a starting point. Also read about `regex`...

Comment: just let me say this is harder than it seems to be. People want to express themselves, so if you block bad words, people will find out alternative ways to express them, like PRON or P.O.R.N. and things like this

Answer (score 0):

The naive (or brute force) solution is to create a `Collection` of "forbidden" words and replace any of them if found in the input String. This won't help you with bad words that contain typos, however, so it's not a perfect solution. And this solution is not very efficient, since it scans the input String once for every bad word in your dictionary. You should use it only if your input String and number of bad words are small.

```
String input = "....";
for (word : badWords) {
    input = input.replace(word,"****"); // which can be improved to return a
                                        // number of `*` matching that length of
                                        // the bad word it replaces.
}
```

There are more efficient (and complicated) ways to search for the bad words. You can, for example, store all the bad words in a tree, and then, for each word in the input String, traverse the tree to see if that word matches any of the bad words. This would allow you to scan the input String just once, instead of one time for each bad word in your dictionary.

Let's say your bad words are "bar", "bark", "bard" and "sit". Your tree would look like this :

```
          ROOT
          /  \
         b    s
        /      \
       a        i
      /          \
     r            t
    /\
   k  d
```

This is a very small example, and it only make sense to implement something like this if your have lots of bad words or the input text is huge.

Now, here's some pseudo code of what you could do :

```
String[] inputs = input.split(" ");
for (String word : inputs) {
    Node curr = ROOT; // begin at the root of the tree
    boolean isBad = true;
    for (int i = 0; i < word.length; i++) {
        char c = word.charAt(i);
        if (the curr node of the tree has a child whose char = c)
            curr = that child node;
        else {
            isBad = false;
            break; // current word is ok
        }
    }
    if (isBad)
      // replace the bad word that was just found
}
```

This is just a partial example and doesn't cover all cases.

Answer (score 0):

You may maintain a registry of all such words on your server side (maybe in a property file)  and test required input fields against this registry. If the input word is one of the words maintained in the registry, replace with `*`.

Answer (score 0):

You need to see the [Java.lang.String.replace()](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/lang/string_replace_sequence.htm) method.

Then you learn [REGEX](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_regular_expressions.htm).